# Multiple outputs for one key for reducer function, Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

What I need to do and am having some trouble doing is to have two values output for one key as the output to my reduce function. The reduce function receives data in the form of an Id and a list of integers associated with that Id. It needs to output that Id, the average of the integers in the list and the length of the list.

However, the implementation of the reduce function is supposed to have `OutputCollector <Text, IntWritable>` as an argument which clearly limits the number of outputs associated with each key to 1.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Hadoop version: 2.0.0

Comment: Your question is so poorly worded that neither of the two answers you have received so far could be considered wrong, yet they are completely different.  I can think of a third interpretation which leads to yet another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use MultipleOutputs. In the Job:

```
MultipleOutputs.addMultiNamedOutput(job,
            "Name",
            SequenceFileOutputFormat.class, Text.class,
            Writable.class);
```

In the reducer :

```
multipleOutputs.getCollector
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few answers to your vague question.

You can call `collect()` as many times as you want for the same key if you don't mind each of the data (length and mean) appearing on its own record in a blended output.  This could be accomplished by writing the key differently to distinguish the different records types, as follows:

```
oc.collect( new Text( k.toString() + " mean", mean );
oc.collect( new Text( k.toString() + " length", length );
```

OR

You should choose a different value type V3 instead of `IntWritable`.  Either create a `PairOfIntWritable` or use an `ArrayWritable` to shove whatever you want into a single call to `collect`.  Then the length and mean can be "fields" of the value for a single record for each key.

OR

If you absolutely have to use `IntWritable`, use an [invertible pairing function](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) to combine two integers into one.  You'll need to insure that you can't exceed the maximum value of an `IntWritable` with any possible pair you could generate from your input data.

OR

Use `MultipleOutputs` to send one record each to a different file distinguished by name, so the part-r-nnnnn contain means and length-r-nnnnn contain lengths, for example.  The JavaDoc on `MultipleOutputs` explains its use.